# Updating Mesa for instaling Vulkan

Tags: debian, software-installation, intel, vulkan, mesa

I found a post about Vulkan for Intel graphic card
([the topic is here](https://01.org/linuxgraphics/blogs/jekstrand/2016/open-source-vulkan-drivers-intel-hardware))
and decided to try out. It said that it will be available for 5th and higher generation Intel cards. I have an old 3rd gen card which will probably not work, right? I mean Vulkan is a library, so the problem is on Mesa which is basically run Vulkan, and it will work only with new cards, right? Is there any way to run a Vulkan on my old Intel?

I looked more about mesa. 
According to [Mesa](http://www.mesa3d.org/), they released version 13.0.3. 
After command `glxinfo | grep Open`  I found out that I have:

```
OpenGL renderer string: Mesa DRI Intel(R) Ivybridge Mobile 
OpenGL core profile version string: 3.3 (Core Profile) Mesa 10.3.2
OpenGL core profile shading language version string: 3.30
```

Time to update, even if Vulkan will not work, installing a new version of Mesa is good. For that, we need to download the new mesa, and according to [Mesa](http://www.mesa3d.org/) :

> The general approach is the standard:
>    ./configure
>      make
>      sudo
>   make install

But [Debian - wiki](https://wiki.debian.org/DontBreakDebian#Don.27t_.27make_install.27) says that this is not a good idea. How can it be installed correctly; is there any way to do it from apt-get? Is it possible to install it on my system? If it is possible, which dependency must I install/update to do so? On [Intel's](https://01.org/linuxgraphics/downloads) website, I found out a list/recipe. Do I need install all of that list:

> 2016Q4 Intel Graphics Stack Recipe Released Notes by 20 Dec, 2016

in order to update my Mesa?

System : Debian GNU/Linux 8 (jessie) 64-bit

Graphics : Intel® Ivybridge Mobile

`glxinfo | grep Open` 
 : 
Intel Corporation 3rd Gen Core processor Graphics Controller
...
Kernel driver in use: i915

/-------------------/

I'm asking in order to understand how it work, and how to do it correctly, before I will do anything.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In Debian, the easiest way to get newer Mesa drivers is to use the backported packages; as `root`:

```
echo deb http://httpredir.debian.org/debian jessie-backports main > /etc/apt/sources.list.d/jessie-backports.list
apt-get update
apt-get -t jessie-backports install mesa-vulkan-drivers
```

should do the trick; as of May 2017 that will install version 13.0.6.

If you're a little more adventurous you could try building another version of the Mesa package yourself:

```
sudo apt-get install devscripts build-essential
dget http://httpredir.debian.org/debian/pool/main/m/mesa/mesa_17.1.0-1.dsc
cd mesa-17.1.0
dpkg-buildpackage -us -uc
```

The last step will complain about missing build-dependencies, install them and try again.

Finally, the Debian X Strike Force publish [instructions for building Mesa from upstream](https://pkg-xorg.alioth.debian.org/howto/build-mesa.html), although they're focused on running a local build just to verify bug fixes, not on replacing the installed Mesa.

Comment: So is it a good idea to build package myself for the latest Mesa, or use the older version?

Comment: If you want to try building the package yourself, go for it, it's risk-free: if it doesn't work, you won't have broken anything, and if it does, you'll get packages that you can install and uninstall cleanly. Using the older version is easier, that's all.

Comment: well after doing the first variant and reboot, the glxinfo still told me that it  10.3.2 instead  of 12.0.4

Comment: Ah, if you want newer GL drivers you need to upgrade `libgl1-mesa-dri` and `libgl1-mesa-glx` (which should upgrade the other required packages): `apt-get -t jessie-backports install libgl1-mesa-{dri,glx}`. The recipe in the answer installs the Vulkan drivers only.

Comment: @StephenKitt @alex_mike I did try to upgrade the `libgl1-mesa-*` packages but running `glxinfo` reports my OpenGL version to be 3.0 while card supports 4.1. what am I missing? Meanwhile I'm trying to follow [how-to-install-the-latest-mesa-version-on-debian-9-stretch-linux](https://linuxconfig.org/how-to-install-the-latest-mesa-version-on-debian-9-stretch-linux), but I'm not sure if it's going to help

Comment: @StephenKitt  Well. I fix all my problem with mesa on debian by updating kernel for the newest version as possible than update all drivers and packages and then installing mesa. And only then I got a correct version of opengl and everything. I think it because debian strict policy with stable packages.